# How can I get my Firefox Addons page to display again?

Tags: firefox, performance, browser-addons

My Firefox has lately been significantly slower than usual.

I wanted to see if I could delete an add-on that might be causing the problem but when I click on add-ons, it never shows me the add-on page:

[image]

**What is causing this and how can I get my add-on page to display again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to click on the "Extensions" button and it will show your installed extensions.

(I don't understand either why firefox try to show extensions from the website....)

Best regards,